# How do I remove horizontal scroll bar at the bottom of my page CSS

Tags: html, css

I've had a problem with a page of mine where the scroll bar at the bottom would remain no matter what. (Check out: https://myanimelist.net/animelist/Looshi ) to see what I'm talking about. Is there any way that I can remove that **horizontal scroll bar** no matter the resolution of the screen I visit the page on? It's very unaesthetic and I've been trying to look at the property to modify or a solution but to no avail.

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gg8TZQ0BJhbRIYwf70KBwH0Bdkicp-_eMVd8phgH1E8/edit?usp=sharing
This following document is all the CSS code. I feel like it must be something trivial I'm missing but I've been trying for days!

I tried adding

```
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
```

But I guess I added those properties to the wrong element thus it's not really working..

Comment: You mean the horizontal scrollbar that appears when resizing the window?

Comment: where did you add the `overflow-x: hidden` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution is to avoid overflowing content. In your case change selector to:

`.list-item:nth-of-type(4n+1) .data:not(.title):not(.status):not(.score):not(.progress):not(.chapter):not(.volume), .list-item:nth-of-type(5n + 1) .data:not(.title):not(.status):not(.score):not(.progress):not(.chapter):not(.volume)`

I changed 5n to 4n+1

Comment: you are rite @Alan but our answer should stick with the title of the question.

Comment: well, you right now too :) but best solution for removing scroll bar is avoiding overflow body content

Answer (score 3):

Just apply `style="overflow-x: hidden;"` to your `<body>` tag

I have inspected your issue and checked it solves

Should look like the below

```
<body class="ownlist anime" data-work="anime" data-query="{&quot;status&quot;:7}" data-owner="" data-owner-id="4457115" data-owner-name="Looshi" style="
    overflow-x: hidden;
">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `body` element in `css`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the `css` for the `class`  `list-table tbody.list-item`

and the way you generated code is not correct i guess. You need to generate `tr` dynamically in `loop` not `tbody`.

[image: Click to see the image]